# Eloquent JavaScript, 2nd Edition, Exercise 5.3 Historical Life Expectancy

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

This problem asks us to take an array of objects (that each contain information about a person), group these people by which century they died in, and then produce the average age a person lived to for each century.

I've viewed the textbook solution, but I can't understand why my solution doesn't work as well.

I'm able to produce an object comprised of arrays for each century, and the elements in each array are the ages that I need to average:

```
{16: [47, 40],
 17: [40, 66, 45, 42, 63],
 18: [41, 34, 28, 51, 67, 63, 45, 6, 43, 68, …],
 19: [72, 45, 33, 65, 41, 73],
 20: [73, 80, 90, 91, 92, 82],
 21: [94]}
```

They provide us with an average function:

```
function average(array) {
  function plus(a, b) { return a + b; }
  return array.reduce(plus) / array.length;
}
```

So then I run this code:

```
var obj = group(ancestry); //this is the object of arrays from above
for (var century in obj) {
  console.log(century + ": " + average(century));
}
```

I'm supposed to get this:

```
// → 16: 43.5
//   17: 51.2
//   18: 52.8
//   19: 54.8
//   20: 84.7
//   21: 94
```

Instead I get this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (line 3 in function average) 
 called from line 26
//where line 3 is the third line in the average function
//and line 26 is the "console.log..." line from the last paragraph of code
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Oh, I didn't notice it before, but you're using the [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, and then operating on the key instead of the value.

Make your loop as so:

```
for (var century in obj) {
  console.log(century + ": " + average(obj[century]));
}
```

---

Read up on the [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function. The reduce function expects as the first argument a callback - a function which operates on, and returns a mutable object (object or array).

From the MDN link itself:

> reduce executes the callback function once for each element present in the array, excluding holes in the array, receiving four arguments: the initial value (or value from the previous callback call), the value of the current element, the current index, and the array over which iteration is occurring.

Comment: *callback* is the **first** argument.   `arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])`

Comment: Thanks @PM77-1... It was my bad, I rewrote that sentence 3-4 times before posting, and by mistake left it as second instead of first.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That is a better description of the function than what is defined in the Eloquent JavaScript text.